# If A has the same cardinality as its intersection with B, then A is a subset of B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'd like to prove that, for finite sets A and B,

$\left(\left\vert{A}\right\vert=\left\vert{A \cap B}\right\vert\right) \to A\subseteq B$

This seems like it should be true (and a piece of code depends on it, actually), but I can't seem to find a proof for it.

I found the more specific [intersection with subset is subset](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_with_Subset_is_Subset) proof, but I don't see a way to directly use those results when it comes to the looser condition of equal cardinality.

Comment: $A= A\cap B $ means what to you?

Comment: First assume it is not true. Then try to get a contradiction.

Comment: @Incurrence, are the cardinality operators not rendering for you?

Comment: @Alexw They are rendering, perhaps consider my question again.

Comment: @Incurrence, not sure what you're getting at.  I have no such assumption that $A = A \cap B$.

Comment: @Alexw $A= A\cap B$ means that $A\subseteq B$...

Comment: @Alexw I hope my answer clarifies both of your concerns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $A$ is not a subset of $B$.Then $A\cap B$ is a proper subset of $A$. Then since these are finite sets $|A|>|A\cap B|$. But $|A|=|A\cap B|$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I had a feeling it would be a proof by contradiction... Is there a proof available for $A \not \subseteq B \to A \cap B \subset A$?  It looks obvious from the Venn diagram, at least.

Comment: @Alexw I think you may not understand how the intersection works

Comment: @alexw: If $A$ is not a subset of $B$, then either they are disjoint or  not disjoint. Disjoint case gives a trivial result. If not, then there is an element $x\in A$ suct that $x\notin B$. Then $x\notin A\cap B$ also. We know that $ A\cap B\subseteq A$. But because of $x$, we have $A\cap B\subset A$

Comment: @alexw One can do it directly too - "If $|A|=|A\cap B|$, then as they are finite, $A=A\cap B$, hence $x\in A$ implies $x\in A \cap B$ implies $x\in B$ meaning $A\subseteq B$"

Answer (score 1):

$$A\cap B=\{a|a\in A \text{ and } a\in B\}$$

If $A=A\cap B$, then all $a\in A$ are also in $A\cap B$, and hence all $\forall a\in A$, we have  $a\in B$.

Hence $A\subseteq B$.

---

$A\cap B \subseteq A,A\cap B \subseteq B$ are always the case, since all elements in $A\cap B$ MUST be in $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You still haven't convinced me that $\left(\left\vert{A}\right\vert=\left\vert{A \cap B}\right\vert\right) \to \left(A = A \cap B\right)$.

Comment: @Alexw Look at the definition of $A\cap B$ again

Comment: @alexw You know that $|A|$ is the number of elements in $A$ right?

Comment: @alexw: Always we have $A\cap B\subseteq A$. Here it is given that $|A\cap B| =| A|$. That means $A\cap B$ cannot be a proper subset of $A$. Hence, $A\cap B = A$

Comment: @Alexw $|A|=|A\cap B|$ means that all of the elements of $A$ are retained in $A\cap B$ which means that $B$ must have all of these elements.

Comment: @Alexw Note this is all in my answer above.